# Помогите определить тип шифра/полностью декодировать сообщение

Tags: криптография, шифрование

Имею такой набор "слов"...очевидно,что шифр построен на символах 1,5,4,?...в какую сторону копать хз...мы в 16 человек пыхтели...ни одной идеи нормальной...нужно понять каким макаром это зашифровано чтобы был хотябы шанс на декодирование...
Шифер:
?1? ?4??4??4??1? ?4??4??4??4??4??1? ?4??4??4??4??4??5? ?4??4??4??5? ?4??4??4??4??1?! ?1? ?4??4??1? ?1? ?4??4??4??4??1? ?4??4??4??4??4??1? ?4??4??4??4??4??5??1? ?4??4??4??1? ?1? ?4??4??4??4??4??4??5??4??1? ?4??4??4??4??4??4??4??1?? ?4??4??4??4??1? ?4??1? ?4??4??4??5??4??1? ?1? ?4??4??4??4??4??1? ?4??4??4??4??1? ?4??1? ?4??4??4??4??4??4??4??1? ?4??4??4??4??1? ?4??4??4??4??5?!

UPD:если убрать весь шум то выйдет что-то вроде
1 4441 444441 444445 4445 44441! 1 441 1 44441 444441 4444451 4441 1 444444541 44444441? 44441 41 444541 1 444441 44441 41 44444441 44441 44445!

И мы увилим что почти все "слова" кончаются на еденицу,кроме 444445 4445 и 44445

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88669/discussion-on-question-by--------).